# Invalid Linq query using Where

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code:

```
    public ActionResult Details(int orderId)
    {
        var query = from orderDetails in storeDb.OrderDetails
                    where orderDetails.OrderId = orderId
                    select new { orderDetails.Product, orderDetails.Quantity, orderDetails.UnitPrice };

        return View(query);
    }
```

I want to get the rows of orderDetails where the foreign key OrderId is equal to the parameter orderId. However I keep getting the following error: `Error  2   Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool'`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`where orderDetails.OrderId = orderId`

Needs to be

`where orderDetails.OrderId == orderId`

Comment: @Seth since this is the right answer you should mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
where orderDetails.OrderId == orderId
```